# InstantiationError on HornetQDestination with JBOSS/HornetQ

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

When trying to connect to a remote JBOSS+HornetQ, we are getting the error in the subject.  We can connect to a remote HornetQ on a different machine with no trouble.

We are using HermesJMS to try and make a JNDI connection to the JBOSS server and we are able to create the JNDI context, but not attach to any topics/queues/etc.

We are using JBOSS 5.1.0 GA and HornetQ 2.0.0 GA.

Does anyone know what could cause the InstantionError?

Thanks.

Comment: Bit late i suppose, but could you supply a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a classpath issue. (You are probably missing a library, or have a version mismatch)

Anyway, hornetQ 2.0.0.GA is quite old. You should probably try a newer version, with your classpath fixed.